# Connecting T1 to T3 at DXB, different airlines

Tags: dubai, british-airways, emirates

Flying from LHR to DXB arriving at 2345 on BA (terminal 1). Bought a separate ticket (separate PNR) on EK departing at 0215 from T3. I understand that BA will not interline my baggage through to EK so I must reclaim my checked baggage upon arrival at T1 then proceed to check in with EK.

Is this even remotely possible with a 2 1/2 hour connection at DXB? Then same question in reverse a few days later with a 3 hour connection, although I have heard that EK may interline bags to a BA connection.

Comment: On separate tickets? Dubai is _enormous_. [Mahraba](https://www.marhabaservices.com/) can fast-track you and your bags through customs and between terminals but there is a charge for it. Otherwise I'd want at least four hours.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.